# SQL LEFT JOIN behaviour

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join, sql-null

Trying to get a SQL LEFT JOIN to return NULLs where there are no corresponding rows in the other table.

Table 1 - T1

```
id  n
1   aaa       
2   bbb       
3   ccc
```

Table 2 - T2

```
t1_id   t3_id
1   1
2   1
3   1
1   2
3   2
2   3
3   3
```

In T2, note that there is no combination of 2 - 2 or 1 - 3.

```
select * 
from t1
left join t2
on t1.id = t2.t1_id
order by t2.t3_id, t1_id
```

Output:

```
id  n   t1_id   t3_id
1   aaa         1   1
2   bbb         2   1
3   ccc         3   1
1   aaa         1   2
3   ccc         3   2
2   bbb         2   3
3   ccc         3   3
```

I was expecting there to be two additional rows

```
1   aaa         null    null
2   bbb         null    null
```

...corresponding to the previously mentioned missing combinations in T2.

Note the ORDER BY is only there for convenience - it makes no difference to the rows returned.

Please help me understand why this is happening, and how to get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all rows in `t2` in the result set, it should be the first table referenced in the `left join`:

```
select * 
from t2 left join
     t1
     on t1.id = t2.t1_id
order by t2.t3_id, t2.t1_id;
```

EDIT:

You seem to want to *generate* new rows not in the original data.  Use `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring them in:

```
select t3.t3_id, t1.id, t1.n
from (select distinct t2.t3_id from t2) as t3 cross join
     t1 left join
     t2
     on t3.t3_id = t2.t3_id and t2.t1_id
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff.  I have tried both this variation, and the one below using a RIGHT JOIN, and neither show the NULL rows.  To be clear, I am expecting 9 rows returned.  At the moment, only 7 rows are returned.

Comment: @DerekBez . . . You want to generate rows not in the data.  See the edit.

Comment: Yes!  (Don't forget to add t2.t1_id = t1.id to the end of your edited query.)   I also added t2.* to the SELECT, which proves your (edited) solution is correct - NULLs where I need them.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you do want to reference `t1` first in the `FROM`, you would use a `RIGHT JOIN` instead (personally I find these less intuitive but some do prefer them, and they do have their uses when more tables are involved):

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
     RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
ORDER BY t2.t3_id,
         t1_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table1:
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
|  1 | john |
-------------
|  2 | mark |
-------------
|  3 | will |
-------------

table2:
-----------------
| t1_id | t3_id |
-----------------
|   1   |   3   |
-----------------
|   1   |   2   |
-----------------
|   3   |   1   |
-----------------
```

if i want to get table1 through table2:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table2 as t2 
LEFT JOIN table1 as t1
ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
WHERE 1
ORDER BY t1.id ASC;
```

you'll get:

```
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
|  1 | john |
-------------
|  1 | john |
-------------
|  3 | will |
-------------
```

edited:

so the query will get all what's in table2, so (t1_id: 1, t3_id: 3), (t1_id: 1, t3_id: 2), (t1_id: 3, t3_id: 1), then the left join will compare the id of t1 with t1_id in t2 and return all columns in t1 as i wrote *.

Comment: Thanks @moemenRajab.  In your T2, change the data rows as follows:  1 - 3, 1 - 2,  3 - 1.  Remove the WHERE clause.  Do you get three rows returned?

Comment: @DerekBez i changed it and thats what you'll get